# How to infer parameters in statistical inference factoring in different "weight" for each observation?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference

I do have a theoretical question.

Let's assume we have a sample of empirical observations (e.g. financial losses thus real > 0) on which we want to infer a stochastic distribution (e.g. log-normal).

Let's also assume that, within the data, there is a few observations (e.g. 2 of them) which where unlikely to occur (e.g. if we would have made the analysis at another period of time, they would not have been there, neither similar losses, but the rest of the sample would have remain similar).

Q: Is it possible to add a subjectivity, to account for a specific empirical observation only partially (e.g. 50% if we think that this loss return period is not the one seen in the data but twice it) prior to inferring parameters? Ideally in each usual method (MME MLE MQE etc.)

Rational behind is to capture the fact that, during a given a period of observation, a specific observation (a specific loss) should relatively to the other observations have "less weight" than the others.

Comment: It is certainly possible to use weights in models, and using priors is another way to perhaps achieve something close to your goal. It's difficult to answer this well without a clearer example though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares

Comment: Yep. But what about the other methods? MQE, MGE, ...